# How to traverse the inner children of a DOM element

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check if a DOM element contains certain elements. For example, if I have this `p` element:

```js
if ($("#parent").find("U")) {
  alert("found u");
}
if ($("#parent").find("B")) {
  alert("found b");
}
if ($("#parent").find("STRIKE")) {
  alert("found strike");
}
if ($("#parent").find("I")) {
  alert("found i");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="parent">
  <i>
     <u>
      <strike>
        <b>text</b>
      </strike>
     </u>
    </i>
</p>
```

But it is only alerting the `u` element. I don't know why it is not searching the deeper children of the `p` element.

Comment: A tip: Use `console.log(...)`. The benefits being that you don't get hit with UI pausing modals, and console log will display all of the fields of the objects where as alert will show you `[Object object]`.

Comment: Ok ^^ thank you for the tip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you were on track there. I just included the jquery script tag and used the length function to see if the element exists.

See the snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  if ($("#parent").find("U").length) {
    alert("found u");
  }
  if ($("#parent").find("B").length) {
    alert("found b");
  }
  if ($("#parent").find("STRIKE").length) {
    alert("found strike");
  }
  if ($("#parent").find("I").length) {
    alert("found i");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="parent">
  <i>
   <u>
 <strike>
   <b>text</b>
 </strike>
   </u>
  </i>
</p>
```

Comment: erm.. what? if the first worked, the rest would have. wrapping in domready will have no effect if the first is working. (they should have all worked regardless of whether or not the elements existed in the original code)

Answer (score 0):

As-is, your code should `alert()` on *all* of those types whether they are present or not, since `find()` always returns an object, and is thus always true.

You should instead check the `length` of the found collection:

```js
var p = $("#parent")

if (p.find("U").length) {
  console.log("found u");
}
if (p.find("B").length) {
  console.log("found b");
}
if (p.find("STRIKE").length) {
  console.log("found strike");
}
if (p.find("I").length) {
  console.log("found i");
}
if (p.find("div").length) {
  console.log("found div");    // shouldn't see this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="parent">
  <i>
    <u>
      <strike>
        <b>text</b>
      </strike>
    </u>
  </i>
</p>
```